# How to run a 'watch' script along with a 'start' script in my node.js project

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, microservices

I'm writing an app that is composed of microservices (I use [micro](https://github.com/zeit/micro)).

I really like `es6`, so I use `Babel` to make the development process easier. The problem that I have is that I need a script that would compile my `es6` code and restarted the 'server'; I don't know how to achieve this.

Right now I have the following script in my `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "yarn run build && micro",
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/babel src --out-dir lib"
  },
```

When I run `yarn start` my `es6` code compiles successfully and `micro` starts the server. However, if I make changes to my code, I'll have to manually stop the server and run `yarn start` again.

I've tried to change my build script

```
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/babel src --watch --out-dir lib"
```

But in this case the `micro` command does not get executed as the `build` script just watches for changes and blocks anything else from execution. My goal is to have a script that would watch for changes and restart the server if a change occurred (compiling the code beforehand) like in `Meteor`.

Answer (score 0):

One option is using [ParallelShell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parallelshell) module to run shell commands in parallel. You can find an example of how to use it [here](https://codeburst.io/headache-free-ssr-react-js-node-js-and-es6-app-boilerplate-tutorial-267f7be0b7b5)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to `yarn run build & micro` (note the single `&` and not `&&`).

As mentioned by others, [parallelshell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parallelshell) is another good hack ([probably more robust](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parallelshell#motivation) than `&`).